# Footer doesn't go to the bottom

Tags: html, css

My page is divided into 3 pieces. The `header` the `main` and the `footer`.

The `header` is fixed to the top and is `109px` with its `6px` border height so the `main` has a `109px` margin to the top.

I want the `main` to extend over the entire page below the header and to the footer that should, if no content that is available to push it down, rest on the bottom of the screen.

The `footer` is `86px` high because it is `80px` and `6px` for a border at the top. The `footer` goes to the bottom and the `main` extends but if the page is longer than the page the `footer` isn't pushed down.

What can I do to keep the `footer` to the bottom if the content of the `main` is increased?

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------------------- */

main {
  padding-top: 120px;
  /* eigendlich 109px  */
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  /* eigendlich 86px  */
  text-align: center;
}

#all {
  height: 100%;
}

#header {
  background-color: #25211e;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #1d1a18;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 103px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  z-index: 99;
}

#heading {
  font-family: "titlefont";
  color: #c1b497;
  font-size: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #25211e;
  border-top: 6px solid #1d1a18;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 98;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

#credit {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #c1b497;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>My Page</title>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="all">
    <header id="header">
      <h1 id="heading">My Page</h1>
    </header>
    <main id="main">
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
    </main>
    <footer id="footer">
      <p id="credit">FOOTER</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the set height's but on header and footer, remove position absolute from the footer and use viewport units `vh` for the height on `main`, combined with CSS Calc, and you are good to go.

I also added `overflow: hidden` to `main` to make up for the collapsing margin caused by the `h1`, and `box-sizing: border-box` so the padding gets included in the set width.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------------------- */

main {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 86px);
  padding-top: 109px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
  background-color: #25211e;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #1d1a18;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 103px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  z-index: 99;
}

#heading {
  font-family: "titlefont";
  color: #c1b497;
  font-size: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #25211e;
  border-top: 6px solid #1d1a18;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 98;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

#credit {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #c1b497;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div id="all">
  <header id="header">
    <h1 id="heading">My Page</h1>
  </header>
  <main id="main">
    <h2>Content</h2>
    <h2>Content</h2>
    <h2>Content</h2>
    <h2>Content</h2>
    <h2>Content</h2>
    <h2>Content</h2>
    <h2>Content</h2>
    <h2>Content</h2>
  </main>
  <footer id="footer">
    <p id="credit">FOOTER</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try a flexbox sticky footer!

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

header, footer {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

main {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <header><span>header</span></header>
    <main><span>main content</span></main>
    <footer><span>footer</span></footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can change

```
 position: fixed;
```

in your `#footer` CSS

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------------------- */



#all {
  height: 100%;
}

#header {
  background-color: #25211e;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #1d1a18;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 103px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  z-index: 99;
}

#heading {
  font-family: "titlefont";
  color: #c1b497;
  font-size: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
main {
  padding-top: 120px;
  /* eigendlich 109px  */
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  /* eigendlich 86px  */
  text-align: center;
}
#footer {
  background-color: #25211e;
  border-top: 6px solid #1d1a18;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 98;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

#credit {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #c1b497;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
  <div id="all">
    <header id="header">
      <h1 id="heading">My Page</h1>
    </header>
    <main id="main">
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
    </main>
    <footer id="footer">
      <p id="credit">FOOTER</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
```

Comment: OP wants the footer to be pushed down when content overflows, which this won't.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `height: 100%` to `#main`

```
main {
  padding-top: 120px;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please try the solutions you suggest before posting, and if you would, you'd seen this won't work

Answer (score 1):

Make the `body` tag have `min-height: 100%` and remove `height`. What you need to change:

```css
body {
    /* height: 100%; */ Delete
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Here's all the code, in a snippet:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------------------- */

main {
  padding-top: 120px;
  /* eigendlich 109px  */
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  /* eigendlich 86px  */
  text-align: center;
}

#all {
  height: 100%;
}

#header {
  background-color: #25211e;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #1d1a18;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 103px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  z-index: 99;
}

#heading {
  font-family: "titlefont";
  color: #c1b497;
  font-size: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #25211e;
  border-top: 6px solid #1d1a18;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 98;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="all">
    <header id="header">
      <h1 id="heading">My Page</h1>
    </header>
    <main id="main">
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
    </main>
    <footer id="footer">
      <p id="credit">FOOTER</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a solution by changing a bit the order of elements, if this is to be acceptable.

I removed `<div id="all">` and added `<header>` and `<footer>` inside of `<main>`. `<main>` has `min-height: 100%` and `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to accommodate the `<header>` and `<footer>`. `<header>` is fixed at the top and `<footer>` is in absolute positioning at the bottom of `<main>`.

Therefore:

- when the content is less than window size `<main>` has `min-height: 100%`, `<header>` is fixed at the top and `<footer>` goes at the bottom in its absolute positioning
- when the content is larger than the window size `<main>` has `min-height: 100%` so can expand above window size, `<header>` is fixed at top and `<footer>` foes at the bottom of `<main>` which is at the end of `<main>` content

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------------------- */

main {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 120px;
  padding-bottom: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#header {
  background-color: #25211e;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #1d1a18;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 103px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  z-index: 99;
}

#heading {
  font-family: "titlefont";
  color: #c1b497;
  font-size: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #25211e;
  border-top: 6px solid #1d1a18;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 98;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

#credit {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #c1b497;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>My Page</title>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <main id="main">
      <header id="header">
        <h1 id="heading">My Page</h1>
      </header>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <footer id="footer">
        <p id="credit">FOOTER</p>
      </footer>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `position: absolute;` to `position: fixed;`, that should fix it.

The `#footer` div should now look like this;

```
#footer {
  background-color: #25211e;
  border-top: 6px solid #1d1a18;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 98;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}
```

Click here to see it in action: [JSfiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pq0w3xj6/).